# How to take char between digit and bracket?

Tags: c#, regex

We have for egz. `4.7(8+3)` how add multiple character between digit and bracket`4.7*(8+3)`

Comment: Please explain what you are looking for in more detail.  Are you just concerned with the expression `4.7(8+3)`?  Do you need support for any number of nested `()`?  What operators and characters may be in expressions?

Comment: I need support for any number. There may be "()+-*/^" and digits in expression. I would like to change "number(" to "number*(", but when "number+(" then just stay "number+(".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture digit followed by bracket into two groups, then replace matched value with group values and multiple character between them:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d)(\()", "$1*$2")
```

For input `"4.7(5+(8+3)/1(1-2))"` result will be `"4.7*(5+(8+3)/1*(1-2))"`

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: REplace **(** by ***(**

Comment: what if `4.7((8+3)/(5-1))`

Comment: that's good when "5(2+3)" to make "5*(2+3)" ,but in case when "5+(2+3)" it make "5+*(2+3)"

Comment: You both are right but OP said ***"between digit and backet...."***